# Calling ASP Button click through Javascript taking time to execute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I need your expertise regarding executing ASP.Net button click event from Javascript function taking 3-4 seconds to execute. below is the scenario -

I have 1 ASP.Net button (inside Update panel)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSetResponse" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="" ToolTip="" Style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />
```

then below is the javascipt function from which I'm calling button click event.

```
function ParseDataandFill()
{
   // get JSON response and store in hiddenfield
   document.getElementById('<%=btnSetResponse.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

here, when **btnSetResponse** is called it is taking time 2-3 seconds to perform action.

Below is Button click event code-

```
Public Sub btnSetResponse_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSetResponse.Click
    Dim ResponseJSON = New JSONData() Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() ResponseJSON = serializer.Deserialize(Of JSONData)(hdnResponse.Value.ToString) 
    If ResponseJSON.ReceivedResponseData.Trim <> "" Then
    ddlACNO.DataSource =ResponseJSON.ReceivedResponseData
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the actual delay, how do you measure this and can you show it?

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've printed response in console window which gets printed as soon I get response. after that I've called Button click event which is parsing the response and attaching to ComboBox which is taking time.

Comment: I have updated question, Added button click event code

Comment: If this is inside an UpdatePanel, chances are there are Server Postbacks happening. Have you put a breakpoint inside your backend class and checked if somethings hanging in there?

Comment: It is still not clear for me - I do not see what you're measuring in your code. This is relevant because it can be the javascript having performance issues - or your `hdnResponse.Value` is just huge or slow.

Comment: 3-4 seconds is not slow, its normal time to execute, if its 3-4 mins then it consider as slow.

Comment: Well if you click on the button manually does it also take the same time? If it does, then introduction of JS to click the button has little to do with this problem then, right? And thus why introduce additional information that doesn't matter? If a button click takes 3 seconds then clicking it with a human or js not going to change anything, right? So then we have a slow button regardless of how we click that button then, right?

Comment: Hi Albert, The time taken is after printing response in console window to hitting button click event (just to reach the event not completing all actions inside button click event).